# ec2 instance does not open in web

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have setup a vpc with public and private subnets and setup internet gateway and route tables all configured. My EC2 instance has also been created and I can SSH into it and able to ping Google. However, when I try to access the HTTP on the internet It says "Refused to Connect".

What would be some troubleshooting options to fix this issue, I have tried everything, Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`Connection refused` error means that the port is `open`, however the service you tried to connect to wasn't listening at that port. Possibly it did not start or it may not be installed as well.

EC2 instances do not provide a `web server` by default. You need to install a web server on your machine, such as `Apache` or `Nginx`.

Even if such an issue, persists, I would recommend you to check your `Security Group` inbound rules or even `Firewall settings`.